# "File" fieldtype missing when trying to add a new channel field

Tags: file-uploads, fieldtype

My "File" fieldtype is missing when trying to add a new channel field after installing file module and safecracker. - I have tried uninstalling the both modules, but the field type has not come back. I have tried clearing all my caches but nothing is making it return. All previous file field types have disappeared too. ?

Comment: What do you mean by the “add field form”? Are you referring to Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Fields > [your field group name] > "Create a New Channel Field" ?

Comment: Yes - trying to add a new channel field. Normally I see "file" there but its now disappeared.

Comment: Got it - I must have uninstalled the file fieldtype when I uninstalled the file module. (Add-ons > Fieldtypes)

Comment: Cool. Can you post that as the answer down below, and mark it as the best answer, so the next person experiencing this problem can quickly find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Got it - I must have uninstalled the file fieldtype when I uninstalled the file module. (Add-ons > Fieldtypes) –